# Cloth simulation: object loses connection to hook

Tags: animation, physics, cloth-simulation

I want a cable to be dragged by an empty until the cable stretches out. I'm using a cloth simulation. The end of the cable is attached to an empty. However, the simulation works just until a certain frame. Then it loses the connection to the empty. I played around with the shrinking factor. Even though the cable gets longer it still breaks up at the same frame. Thank you for your help!

[image: Cable]

[image: Cable loses connection to empty]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the cache settings and setup end frame properly:

[image]